# Display the value of each bar when cursor hovered on that bar in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart, tooltip

I have written a really simple code which basically number of pets against pets in a locality.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y_axis = [1,2,3,4]
x_axis = ['Dogs','Cats','Otter','Chipmunk']
plt.barh(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.show()
```

Now I want a feature which basically shows the value associated with that bar in form of some tooltip or in front of that bar.
How to do this? Can we do this without the use of subplot?

Comment: @JohanC It throws weird values in tooltip when I change it to barh

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).  The following code is an adaption of a [tutorial example for vertical bars](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bar.html).  For some reason, that example uses `sel.index` instead of `sel.target.index`. Maybe something has changed in matplotlib?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

y_axis = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x_axis = ['Dogs', 'Cats', 'Otter', 'Chipmunk']
plt.barh(x_axis, y_axis)

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
@cursor.connect("add")
def on_add(sel):
    x, y, width, height = sel.artist[sel.target.index].get_bbox().bounds
    sel.annotation.set(text=f"{x_axis[sel.target.index]}: {width:g}",
                       position=(10, 0), anncoords="offset points")
    sel.annotation.xy = (x + width / 2, y + height / 2)
    sel.annotation.get_bbox_patch().set(alpha=0.8)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors horizontal bars]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was enough for my need but can you please explain parameters of sel.annotations.set(). Or maybe share any link to their documentation which explains these? I would like to gather in depth knowledge in this.

Comment: `sel`, the selection object is described [here](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#customization). The docs contain many short examples to showcase the possibilities. `sel.annotation` is the text with box and arrow. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Annotation) to  change its properties.