# How to highlight the bar with a border when moving the mouse over it in the bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, matplotlib-widget

I'm still a beginner and I'm trying to make the edge of the bar of the chart be highlighted (change color) in a mouse movement event when hovering over it. Only the bar over which the mouse hovers should be highlighted. The code shows an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'patch'.

How it should look with the movement of the mouse over the bar.

[image]

```py
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches
%matplotlib qt

df = sb.load_dataset('titanic')

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax = sb.barplot(data = df, y = 'class', x = 'fare')#, edgecolor='k')
ax.grid(linestyle='--', zorder=0, axis='x')
f.tight_layout()

def hover(event):
    if event.y:
       event.inaxes.patch.set_edgecolor('k')

ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', hover)
```

I tried to make hovering the mouse over a bar of the graph, the same if highlighted from the others create an outline (border) in it.

Comment: Maybe [Display the value of each bar when cursor hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70792156/display-the-value-of-each-bar-when-cursor-hovered-on-that-bar-in-matplotlib) is of interest?

Comment: No, this is a simple example, in my real life, it has more than 15 bars next to each other and with labels of people's names, so it's interesting to highlight the bar or maybe even the y-axis label (maybe with a color different, I hadn't thought of that), but I couldn't even get that one.

Comment: You may want to consider a plotting tool like bokeh or plotly instead. Also, I don't think the bar highlighting is particularly helpful, but hover annotations might be. See [How to add a hovering annotation on a bar plot with mplcursors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66320623/7758804)

Comment: No doubt TrentonMcKinney, though, I'm studying matplotlib and seaborn, would it be easier in those 2 libraries?

Comment: The link shows hover annotations for matplotlib / seaborn

Comment: Thanks TrentonMcKinney, I'll take a look at this link, it might help me with what I need. In the real case, there is another click event where the records are shown when clicking on each bar, but this one I managed to do. Therefore, I would like to highlight the bar.